# Absolute path is not working on Windows but works on Mac?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, webstorm, absolute-path

Inside my components package, I have added the package.json as

```
{
"name": "component"
}
```

and using it as

```
import SuccessDialog from '@component/
```

However, this is working fine on Mac but not on Windows. Is there any dependencies need to be cross-checked. I'm using **WebStorm** on Windows and **Visual Studio Code** on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

This React native hack for specifying absolute paths (not officially documented anywhere, as far as I can tell) had never been supported by WebStorm. If you miss this feature, please follow [WEB-23221](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23221) for updates. You can try creating a dummy webpack config like it's suggested in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23221#focus=streamItem-27-2719626.0-0 and specifying a path to it in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Webpack** as a workaround.

Another workaround (if you aren't renaming paths, just making them shorter) is marking a parent folder of `component` directory as **Resource root** (note: not the subdirectory itself, but its parent dir!)

Comment: `Not officially documented means`. It's not a stable feature of React Native? :/

Comment: I have no idea if it's stable or not; just can't find it in React official docs